# search by param values of referenced objects in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, dbref

Is it possible to search based on some param value of a DBRef object in spring data.

eg. say we have two objects, Car, and Company as shown

```
Class Car {

   @Id
   String id;
   String model;
   @DBRef
   Company company;
}

Class Company {

   @Id
   String id;
   String name;
}
```

Can I write a query to fetch all car's of Hyundai company like this,

`Query queryForCars = new Query(Criteria.where("company.name").is("Hyundai")), Car.class)`

It works fine for non referenced objects, but for referenced object it's working in my case.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: MongoDB docs suggest that use manual references intead of DBRef.

Comment: Yes, but I need it in some use cases to be able to eager fetch the referenced objects.

Answer (score 1):

For referenced objects this is how your query should look like:

> Query queryForCars = new
>   Query(Criteria.where("company.$name").is("Hyundai")), Car.class)

Comment: I remember this to work long back, but now doesn't seem to work. Any idea?

Comment: Not getting the result at all! as if the criteria is not matching.